# Telling a generic function its type without passing an example of that type

Tags: swift, generics

I'm creating a generic function to handle Firebase Snapshots and I'm finding that the generic function doesn't know what type to work with unless you tell it explicitly the type by feeding it in the argument.

So I've resorted to a really ugly approach of just creating a blank, for example, User() and feeding it into this function and never touching it again.

Whats a better way of doing this?

```
   func handleSnapshot<T: FirebaseType>(snapshot: FDataSnapshot?, forType type: T) -> [T]? {
      guard let snapshot = snapshot, dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else { return nil }
      var objects = [T]()
      for (uid, dictionary) in dictionaries {
         let theUID = uid as? String ?? "No UID"
         guard let dictionary = dictionary as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else { return nil }

         let object = T(fromDictionary: dictionary, andUID: theUID)
         objects.append(object)
      }
      return objects
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the type object instead of an instance of the type. Also, `andUID:` is bad style.

```
func handleSnapshot<T: FirebaseType>(snapshot: FDataSnapshot?, forType type: T.Type) -> [T]? {
    guard let snapshot = snapshot, dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else { return nil }
    var objects = [T]()
    for (uid, dictionary) in dictionaries {
        let theUID = uid as? String ?? "No UID"
        guard let dictionary = dictionary as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else { return nil }

        if let object = T(fromDictionary: dictionary, uid: theUID) {
            objects.append(object)
        }
    }
    return objects
}
```

Use:

```
// Explicit type declaration is unnecessary but included for clarity.
let doodads: [Doodad]? = handleSnapshot(snapshot, forType: Doodad.self)
```

#### UPDATE

Another approach: add the method to `FirebaseType` in a protocol extension:

```
extension FirebaseType {
    func arrayFromSnapshot(snapshot: FDataSnapshot?) -> [Self]? {
        guard let snapshot = snapshot, dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else { return nil }
        var objects = [Self]()
        for (uid, dictionary) in dictionaries {
            let theUID = uid as? String ?? "No UID"
            guard let dictionary = dictionary as? [NSObject: AnyObject] else { return nil }

            if let object = Self(fromDictionary: dictionary, uid: theUID) {
                objects.append(object)
            }
        }
        return objects
    }
}
```

Use:

```
let doodads = Doodad.arrayFromSnapshot(snapshot)
```

Comment: This is slightly better, but in the end, you're still telling it the type.

Comment: Other than telling it, or having it read your mind, what other way could it know what type you want? Serious question.

Comment: I posted some solutions.  I've also upvoted your answer, because it's certainly better than the solution in the question.

Comment: I've added another solution.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on context, the generic's type can be inferred.

Consider the following simplified example:

```
protocol Bar {
    init(a: Int)
}

func foo<T: Bar>(arg1: Int) -> T {
    return T(a: arg1)
}
```

Here, we don't pass in any information for `T`'s type to be inferred (beyond that it's something that conforms to the `Bar` protocol).

Now, given a class that conforms to the protocol, using explicit type declaration, we can call the method:

```
let x: Baz = foo(3)
```

We can even use the cast syntax:

```
let y = foo(3) as Baz
```

Or if we have a function with a parameter with an explicit type and we are in-lining this method call:

```
func printIt(value: Baz) {
    print(value)
}

printIt(foo(5))
```

Or if we have a class with a property with an explicit type which we are setting:

```
class Z {
    var value: Baz
    init(arg: Baz) {
        value = arg
    }
}

let z = Z(arg: Baz(a: 0))
z.value = foo(4)
```

Importantly, if you must have some way for this information to be determined.

---

It's also worth noting that although the exact error message is different, the error we see here:

```
func generic<T: Bar>(arg: Int) -> T {
    return T(a: arg)
}

let f = generic(2)
```

> Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred

This error is roughly equivalent to the same problem we can see with function overloading:

```
func ambiguous(arg: Int) -> Int {
    return arg
}

func ambiguous(arg: Int) -> Double {
    return Double(arg)
}

let value = ambiguous(2)
```

> Ambiguous use of 'ambiguous'

Despite the different error messages (because the source is fundamentally different), the problem is quite the same, and the solutions to both problems are equivalent.